# Remove last option value from multiple select element using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select

I have two select element and I need to remove last option from both select using jQuery.

**First Select Element**

```
<select class="selBooks" name="select1" >
  <option value="8247(random)">Opt2</option>
  <option value="1939(random)">Opt1</option>
</select>
```

**Second Select Element**

```
<select class="selBooks" name="select2" >
  <option value="8244(random)">Opt3</option>
  <option value="1938(random)">Opt4</option>
</select>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".selBooks option:last").remove();
```

When I try this it only removes last option of second select element. Please guide me if I am doing anything wrong or there is other way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iterate `.selBooks` with loop and remove the last element of that class.

```js
$('.selBooks').each(function() {
  $(this).find("option:last").remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="selBooks" name="select1" >
  <option value="8247(random)">Opt2</option>
  <option value="1939(random)">Opt1</option>
</select>

Second Select Element

<select class="selBooks" name="select2" >
  <option value="8244(random)">Opt3</option>
  <option value="1938(random)">Opt4</option>
</select>

jQuery
```

Answer (score 0):

Try by `name`

```js
    $(".selBooks[name=select1] option:last").remove();
    $(".selBooks[name=select2] option:last").remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="selBooks" name="select1" >
  <option value="8247(random)">Opt2</option>
  <option value="1939(random)">Opt1</option>
</select>
Second Select Element

<select class="selBooks" name="select2" >
  <option value="8244(random)">Opt3</option>
  <option value="1938(random)">Opt4</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `last-child`.

```js
$('.selBooks option:last-child').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="selBooks" name="select1">
  <option value="8247(random)">Opt2</option>
  <option value="1939(random)">Opt1</option>
</select>


<select class="selBooks" name="select2">
  <option value="8244(random)">Opt3</option>
  <option value="1938(random)">Opt4</option>
</select>
```